# Oracle - using synonym as variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

i need to use synonym as variable in a block. I have 2 different schemas with same tables on them and job that switches between schemas making one active. Now I want to write a block checking which schema is active with ALL_SYNONYMS and using result as part of a query.
Here is example:

```
DECLARE
  OWNER VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  SELECT TABLE_OWNER
    INTO OWNER
    FROM ALL_SYNONYMS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE1';
  SELECT *
    FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE2 ;
END;
```

But I’m getting ORA-06550 table or view does not exist, and when i run query itself where i put value from ALL_SYNONYMS it returns result.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing a lot more, I'd say the way to 'fix' it is to fix your design - constantly switching between two schemas as 'active' vs 'inactive' sounds like a design fail of the first order.

Comment: You cannot use 'variable' object names in SQL unless it is dynamic. Lookup the 'execute immediate', in the pl/sql  manual of the version you're using.

Comment: If any of the answers provided solved your problem please accept it. Doing so helps future questioners having the same issue and removes the question form the Unanswered list.  If neither has resolved your issue, then where are they deficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting using symptoms incorrectly. Synonyms are used so *you do not need to know which is active*. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401):

> Synonyms provide both data independence and location transparency.
> Synonyms permit applications to function without modification
> regardless of which user owns the table or view and regardless of
> which database holds the table or view.

You just use the synonym instead of the object itself.

```
create table evens( id integer generated always as identity
                  , val  integer 
                  ) ; 
                  
create table odds( id integer generated always as identity
                  , val  integer 
                  ) ; 
                  
insert all 
   when mod(val,2) = 0 then into evens(val)
   when mod(val,2) = 1 then into odds(val)
  select level val 
    from dual connect by level <= 10; 

-- create the synonym then use it in Select;     
create or replace synonym current_even_odd for evens;  

select * from current_even_odd;

-- now change the synonym, then run the EXACT same query.   
create or replace synonym current_even_odd for odds;  

select *  from current_even_odd;
```

In this case it is not quite *without modification*, you need to change the synonym, But it seems you are trying that already.  
Note: You cannot create a synonym for a schema but must point it to a specific object.

I attempted a db<>fiddle for the above, but it appears it is having problems at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Belayer that the synonym should provide a layer of abstraction on your tables and your procedure shouldn't need to know what the schema is. But the "table or view does not exist" error is likely an issue related to privileges and definer's rights versus invoker's rights.

To directly reference an object in a procedure, the procedure's schema must have a direct grant to the table. However, an ad hoc query only needs a role with privileges on the object. This is why the SQL will work in your IDE but not in the procedure. Ensure the code that modifies objects and switches synonyms is granting privileges to both roles and directly to schemas.

If direct grants are not possible, you will need to modify the procedure to use `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` and change the SQL statements to use dynamic SQL - which can be a huge pain. For example:

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure authid current_user is
    v_count number;
begin
    execute immediate
    q'[
        select count(*)
        from some_table
    ]'
    into v_count;
end test_procedure;
/
```

If you really do need to manually switch between schemas, then you may want to consider using something like `execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema=schema1';` in the procedure and using dynamic SQL for all of the querying.